# Have a shutdown timer like OS X?

Tags: shutdown

I wanted to ask if it was possible to have the shutdown dialog box also display timer for 60 seconds after which it shuts down automatically, without adding a ppa.

I am aware of doing it in the terminal (`sudo shutdown -P 1`) but just prefer to be lazy, late at night, and press the shutdown button with the screen staying on for 60 seconds while it gives me enough light to walk to the bed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [gshutdown](http://gshutdown.tuxfamily.org/en/index.php).

Install from software center.

Now open `gshutdown` and adjust settings as per your need.

To adjust delay, select `After a delay`

[image: img]

You can enable notification for `gshutdown` in Edit --> preferences --> Misc

---

Alternatively you can use [complexshutdown](https://launchpad.net/complexshutdown) and [easyshutdown](https://launchpad.net/easyshutdown).

Download [.deb](https://launchpad.net/easyshutdown/trunk/0.6/+download/easyshutdown_0.6_all.deb) for easyshutdown and install it via software center.

*EDIT*: (thanks to [codingbear](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/3719/codingbear) )

From [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/easyshutdown/+bug/1285020), if  easy shutdown is notworking open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-get install consolekit
```

Comment: Hi @Ravan, gshutdown didnt work as even if shutdown is selected it only logs off (By the way a big thank you for including a pic for demonstrating gshutdown). Then I tried easyshutdown and complexshutdown and both did nothing when selected shutdown. Then on checking on the [net](https://goo.gl/Jc1Mwe) I found the solution was to do: sudo apt-get install consolekit. And then they work. I only needed one so I kept complexshutdown as if in future if I needed more options...who knows...but anyways thanks again for giving those links to the .debs and getting this issue resolved.

Comment: @codingbear thanks for your input, I edited my answer :)

Comment: Hey @Ravan, thanks for adding that part, it will help others with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I mean, you could just add a `sleep 60 &&` before your `shutdown -P 1`, turn that into a shell script, I guess. You would have no visible timer but it should give you 60 seconds before shutting down your pc.

BTW working with a bright displays as the only light source, late at night, up until 60 seconds before literally going to bed, is seriously messing with your sleep cycle, pal ;)

Comment: Thanks for replying so quickly. I went to bed last night after posting my question and hence only saw the replies to my question now on Sunday night. I am just used to having a nice mac gui showing me that its gonna shutdown so wanted the same since I have now got Elementary OS installed on my desktop. But just to add on Ravan's answer helped in getting that.